# RegEx to validate for-loop header in Python

Tags: python, regex, for-loop

I took a string input from user that is a `for-loop header` and need to validate it using regex. It verifies successfully upto `in` keyword but what should I do for `range():` or `variable:` matching in the end?

```
import re
loop_header = input("Enter the for loop header: ")
print(re.search(r'for[\s]+[a-zA-Z]+[\S][0-9]*[\s]+in[\s]+', loop_header))
```

I am not able to figure out how to validate the ending part of loop header.

Comment: and what with `for ... in enumerate(...):` or `for ... in zip(...):` or `for ... in data[1:]:` or `for key, value in data.items():` and many other situations? Using single regex can be not enough. It may need parser create with tools like [SLY](https://sly.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [PLY](https://www.dabeaz.com/ply/)

Comment: I am working with regex to validate just `variable` and `range()` for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the regex pattern slightly modified (now taking variable number of non-space characters in the iterator, and ensuring a colon at the end), the following 4 different for-loop headers can be correctly matched:

```py
import re

loop_headers = [
    "for i in [1, 2, 3]:",
    "for num in [1, 2, 3]:",
    "for i in (1, 2, 3):",
    "for word in enumerate(['and', 'now', 'for', 'something', 'completely', 'different']):",
]

regex = re.compile(r"for[\s]+[a-zA-Z]+[\S]*[0-9]*[\s]*in[\s]*(range\(.*\)|enumerate\(.*\)|zip\(.*\))?.*:$")

for loop_header in loop_headers:
    print(re.search(regex, loop_header))
```

Returning

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 18), match='for i in [1, 2, 3]:'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 20), match='for num in [1, 2, 3]:'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 18), match='for i in (1, 2, 3):'>
<re.Match object; span=(0, 84), match="for word in enumerate(['and', 'now', 'for', 'something', 'completely', 'different']:'>
```

You could then additionally have a second regex to require `range`, `enumerate`, `zip` etc. around the iterable, e.g.:

```py
regex_2 = re.compile(
    r"for[\s]+[a-zA-Z]+[\S]*[0-9]*[\s]*in[\s]*(range\(.*\)|enumerate\(.*\)|zip\(.*\))+:$"
)
```